# Need help with API integration

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, integration, journeybuilder

We are looking for support on API integration and designing some custom activity in the journey builder -

I have a few questions on this -

How exactly to get the client ID and secret? 
Where and how to initiate with the custom code? 
For which functionality we need support from the om IT team?
Please suggest your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create an [Install Package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/install-packages.htm).

After that: [Register Endpoint for Custom Journey Builder Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/define-jb-extension-app-center.htm)

Please be advised that you need to create the Install Package in the same business unit you wish the custom Journey Builder activity to be available.

When it comes to the way how to build the entire solution, [read the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm) and watch the [Create Your Own Journey Builder Activities](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BbaUkhdtqTQ) - those resources are really easy to find online when you search for "custom Journey Builder activity" and it's probably the reason you are getting down voted.